# Is Cotton Wool an acceptable substitute for Hamster bedding?

Tags: hamsters, bedding

I've got two Roborovski Hamsters which both have good sized cages. I like to try and change their bedding frequently which obviously increases the cost of the bedding.

It seems there are two types of material required for a hamster:

- Absorbent shavings to cover the ground
- [Softer bedding to build a bed with](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B005AIPPVQ/ref=s9_acsd_top_hd_bw_bVufAN_c_x_2_w)

Buying in bulk seems to be alright for the shavings but less so for the softer stuff. In terms of price, a bag of cotton wool balls (with no additives) costs far less than the softer packs of bedding.

Is there a downside or issue with using cotton wool balls (or small pieces of a larger sheet of cotton wool) as a cheaper substitute for the hamsters?

#### Potential issues I could think of:

- Perhaps cotton wool is less absorbent
- Maybe the fibres would get caught around their legs or something?

---

To clarify, I only want to replace the more expensive soft bedding not the shavings.

Comment: Growing up, my cousins had a hamster. They used wool for its bedding. We went to feed it one evening, and it was dead. It had swallowed some of the wool and had a string coming out of its mouth. It had choked or suffocated. Definitely advise against wool-like bedding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I checked my best source for small animal Keeping (German site: [Die Brain](http://www.diebrain.de/hi-gehege.html#hazu))
What they advise is:

- Hay
- Straw
- Toilet paper
- (Shredded) paper (Make sure it has no chemicals on it, the more natural, the better)
- Dried leaves
- hemp

Cotton is explicitly NOT recommeded! Anything that the hamster can get tangled in should be avoided.
But as Toilet Paper made the list, there is your cheap alternative :).

Answer (score 6):

### Cotton Wool Dangers

There are some dangers to cotton wool such as:

- Ingestion - Intestinal blockage
- Limbs can get tangeled

Hamsters LOVE to burrow so having a substrate where they can dig and hide is best. It acts as environmental enrichment as well as a safe place to hide.

Layna has added a nice list of burrowing/bedding materials however I would only use them in one location of the cage (with the exception of paper based substrates).

1. Hay/straw/dried leaves does not absorb urine or odors well
2. Hemp seems a bit hard and pointy, this might be a German thing - we don't see this type of bedding in Canada but it looks similar to woodchips.

### Why not woodchips?

Woodchips have been known to cause some issues in out critters some examples:

- Aspen - Bumble-foot, eye injuries (chips are hard and pointy).
- Pine - known to cause respiratory ailments from the fine dust particles and phenols.
- Cedar - A harder chip that also contain phenols.

### Great bedding choices

- Toilet paper, shredded paper - only downfall is it does not absorb smell very well.
- Carefresh (like you currently use)
- [Living world Fresh N Comfy](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Hagen-61262-Living-World-Bedding/dp/B0035HBGR6) (my personal favorite, absorbs smell VERY well)

### How to save money?

Litterbox for your hamster! Hamsters tend to pee and poo in a specific area of their enclosure, purchase a litter box for him to use. This will reduce the amount of full enclosure cleanings you need to do, just replace the substrate you use in the litterbox instead!

[How to Potty Train a Hamster](https://www.wikihow.com/Potty-Train-a-Hamster)